# How to get extendedState width of JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

- I have a JFrame of which extended state option is set to MAXIMIZE_BOTH
- When i want to get the width of the JFrame it returns 0.

so WHY?

Comment: i will position a dialog box to the center of it.

Comment: Is there any method other than getWidth() that returns the extendedState dimension?

Comment: `myDialog.setLocationRelativeTo(myFrame)`

Comment: The width of mydialog changes after it is initialized

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Oh xD again that message

Comment: @MOD, you are wasting our time. You have been asked for an SSCCE. You aren't describing your code or question properly because based on what you have said the code should work. So instead of posting smart alec comments when asked for a SSCCE, why don't you actually do it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - I have a JFrame of which extended state option is set to MAXIMIZE_BOTH

[JFrame.getExtendedState()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#getExtendedState%28%29) returns proper state

> - When i want to get the width of the JFrame it returns 0.

any coordinated are accesible after

1. `pack()` is called
2. for already visible container on the screen

Comment: the container is visible but getWidth() still returns 0

Comment: then there must be two `JFrames`, one of them isn't visible or initialized, remove all code about `extends JFrame`

Comment: i created new application and a new JFrame set to MAXIMIZE_BOTH and after calling pack() method i called getWidth() and printed the result. It is 123. My screen width is 1440

Comment: eeeerght you pretty ignored an  [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/),  [I'll edit an post with FullScreen in this thread, have to waiting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15164485/making-a-single-component-full-screen), really why do you shoting to the dard :-)

Comment: Yes it gives the width now :D.